# Leopard geckos and quarantine

Tags: leopard-geckos

I have been recently acquiring new Leo's for my collection and have several new additions set up in quarantine. I am unsure as to how long I should keep them separated from the main reptile room. Information is spotty at best saying anywhere from 1 week up to one month. I just want to make sure that I am doing the right thing by all my animals, both the older ones in my collection and the newer. Any information is welcomed, as I am relatively new to the husbandry for this species.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, 4-6 weeks is considered a good quarantine time. You can choose how long to quarantine, but what you're really looking for is whether the new animal is presenting any signs of diseases that it could transmit to your other geckos. Some diseases, such as mites or respiratory infections, you should be able to detect quickly, within the first week of observation. Other diseases, such as viral diseases (herpesvirus, iridovirus, etc) and some bacterial diseases, may not present themselves visually for up to a month.

While the animal is in quarantine, it's often best to keep them on simple substrates (paper towels is best, in my opinion, because it's easiest to see mites and feces, which are often indicative of ill health) and observe them periodically throughout the day, particularly at feeding time. It's also helpful to weigh the animal consistently (with my snakes, I weigh before every feeding. With a gecko, I would weigh every 3-4 days or so). Any drops in weight are concerning and the quarantine should be extended until the animal appears to be gaining or maintaining weight again.

Comment: thanks for confirming my thoughts on the subject. We do weigh our geckos once a week and keep a close eye on them. needless to say we also wash our hands between handling one and moving to the next.